# finding the percentiles of a transformed weibull.

Tags: linear-transformations, percentile

[assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HUTH.jpg)

[question from the textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klIrJ.png)

please i need help on these question. I was asked to use the data in 102 on the second image i named "question from the textbook" to answer question 1.I have done the a part of question 1 remaining the b part. My lecturer said he wants to see the solution because i used R. 
I would appreciate the assistance of the wonderful forum.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Comment: Writing the assignments in your post instead of posting the photo will increase your chance to get an answer.

Comment: ok i will show the effort i made and also write the assignment instead of the photo.Thanks a lot